# Is there possible to track target phone without Network

Tags: android

I wish to do a GPS tracking system in android. This system will get the location from client cell phone and sent to the server via network. So that the admin can track all the client location.

But the question is if the client is move to other country, the client cell phone is no network any more. Is still possible to track the client location without the network? By using GPS or someway else?

Comment: not possible as per you said. For admin you have need to store data on server.

Answer (score 0):

Just put data in local storage/db in case when there is no network. When network will appear, send cached data to server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a project like yours, the GPS can be obtained without network and saved to an embedded database